# Как объединить два массива разной длиной по дате PHP

Tags: php, массивы, php7

нужна помощь, есть 2 массива.

**Первый массив**

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [countid] => 4
            [datecount] => 2020-09-26
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [countid] => 3
            [datecount] => 2020-09-27
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [countid] => 4
            [datecount] => 2020-09-28
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [countid] => 2
            [datecount] => 2020-09-29
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [countid] => 14
            [datecount] => 2020-09-30
        )
)
```

**Второй массив**

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [countid2] => 1
            [datecount] => 2020-09-28
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [countid2] => 13
            [datecount] => 2020-09-30
        )
)
```

**Задача**

Объединить два массива в один, путем создания нового массива, чтобы на выходе получилось так

```
Array(
    [notvisit] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 13
        )

    [visits] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 14
        )

    [date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 26.09
            [1] => 27.09
            [2] => 28.09
            [3] => 29.09
            [4] => 30.09
        )
)
```

Делал так, но на выходе дублируются даты и данные:

```
$tmpdata = [];
foreach($tmpdatas1 as $item) {
    foreach($tmpdatas2 as $item2) {
    if($item['datecount'] == $item2['datecount']){  
    $tmpdata['notvisit'][]     = $item2['countid2'];
    $tmpdata['visits'][]  = $item['countid'];   
    $tmpdata['date'][] = date("d.m",strtotime($item['datecount']));
    }else{
    $tmpdata['notvisit'][]     = '0';
    $tmpdata['visits'][]  = $item['countid'];   
    $tmpdata['date'][] = date("d.m",strtotime($item['datecount']));
    }
    }   
}
```

выводит такой массив, а нужно чтобы не дублировались

```
Array(
    [notvisit] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 13
        )

    [visits] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 2
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 14
            [9] => 14
        )

    [date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 26.09
            [1] => 26.09
            [2] => 27.09
            [3] => 27.09
            [4] => 28.09
            [5] => 28.09
            [6] => 29.09
            [7] => 29.09
            [8] => 30.09
            [9] => 30.09
        )
)
```

Comment: Уточните, по какому принципу прикрепляется второй массив? Если точнее, то что должно происходить при нахождении общих дат в обоих массивах? Сейчас у Вас в этом случае и добавляется новый массив данных. Если в итоге у Вас должно получиться только 5 элементов, то Вам видимо надо либо складывать, либо вычитать значения, а не добавлять новый массив вместо этого. Напишите, что должно происходить при нахождении общей даты и обязательно поможем.

Comment: это вывод из двух таблиц mysql, просмотры и клики, нужно вывести эти данные и объединить их по дате для построения  графика highcharts.js, чтобы в конечном массиве были данные - просмотры и клики, и объединяет их дата, даже если у таблица кликов нет даты, то ставиться значение 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$tmpdatas1 = [['countid' => '4', 'datecount' => '2020-09-26'],
    ['countid' => '3', 'datecount' => '2020-09-27'],
    ['countid' => '4', 'datecount' => '2020-09-28'],
    ['countid' => '2', 'datecount' => '2020-09-29'],
    ['countid' => '14', 'datecount' => '2020-09-30']];

$tmpdatas2 = [['countid2' => '1', 'datecount' => '2020-09-28'],
    ['countid2' => '13', 'datecount' => '2020-09-30']];


$tmpdata = [];
foreach($tmpdatas1 as $item) {
    $val = 0; // заводим переменную для каждого элемента первого массива
    foreach($tmpdatas2 as $item2) {
        if($item['datecount'] == $item2['datecount']){
            $val += $item2['countid2']; // Если найдено, то складываем значение
        }
    }
    $tmpdata['notvisit'][] = $val; // Выводим данные
    $tmpdata['visits'][] = $item['countid'];
    $tmpdata['date'][] = date("d.m",strtotime($item['datecount']));
}
print_r($tmpdata);
```

Comment: Супер, оказалось все так просто) Спасибо

Comment: @GENESIS Рад помочь ) Да иногда просто нужен взгляд со стороны.